# Passing a File path as a parameter in Postman

Tags: url, parameters, postman, url-parameters

So I am trying to pass a filerepo path as a url parameter in Postman, but it keeps saying its a bad request.
Example:
http://url/api/C:\File

I have also tried the url encoded version, but postman still says bad request:
http://url/api/C%3A%5CFile

Comment: Are you sure that `http://url/api/C:\File` is correct? Can you add image to prove it?

Comment: This is a very late response but this was just an issue with passing in a string that contained "\" and "/" in the URL parameters. I ended up just passing the the string in the request body instead of in the URL.  i.e. { "FileRepo": "C:\File" } in the json request body.